# NameError SciPy in Keras Data Augmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy

I am encountering an issue while attempting to utilize data augmentation with Keras in Python. Despite having installed SciPy successfully and importing it at the beginning of my script, I am facing a Nameerror saying that `name 'scipy' is not defined` when applying data augmentation.

```py
import scipy
gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10)
img = np.array(cv2.imread(img_path))
gen_img = gen.flow(np.expand_dims(img, axis=0))
plt.imshow(gen_img[0])
```

The error message I receive is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "NameError",
    "message": "name 'scipy' is not defined",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[52], line 1
----> 1 gen_img[0]

File c:\\Users\\ADMIN\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\preprocessing\\image.py:116, in Iterator.__getitem__(self, idx)
    112     self._set_index_array()
    113 index_array = self.index_array[
    114     self.batch_size * idx : self.batch_size * (idx + 1)
    115 ]
--> 116 return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)

File c:\\Users\\ADMIN\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\preprocessing\\image.py:801, in NumpyArrayIterator._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    799 x = self.x[j]
    800 params = self.image_data_generator.get_random_transform(x.shape)
--> 801 x = self.image_data_generator.apply_transform(
    802     x.astype(self.dtype), params
    803 )
    804 x = self.image_data_generator.standardize(x)
    805 batch_x[i] = x

File c:\\Users\\ADMIN\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\preprocessing\\image.py:2013, in ImageDataGenerator.apply_transform(self, x, transform_parameters)
   2010 img_col_axis = self.col_axis - 1
   2011 img_channel_axis = self.channel_axis - 1
-> 2013 x = apply_affine_transform(
   2014     x,
   2015     transform_parameters.get(\"theta\", 0),
   2016     transform_parameters.get(\"tx\", 0),
   2017     transform_parameters.get(\"ty\", 0),
   2018     transform_parameters.get(\"shear\", 0),
   2019     transform_parameters.get(\"zx\", 1),
   2020     transform_parameters.get(\"zy\", 1),
   2021     row_axis=img_row_axis,
   2022     col_axis=img_col_axis,
   2023     channel_axis=img_channel_axis,
   2024     fill_mode=self.fill_mode,
   2025     cval=self.cval,
   2026     order=self.interpolation_order,
   2027 )
   2029 if transform_parameters.get(\"channel_shift_intensity\") is not None:
   2030     x = apply_channel_shift(
   2031         x,
   2032         transform_parameters[\"channel_shift_intensity\"],
   2033         img_channel_axis,
   2034     )

File c:\\Users\\ADMIN\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\preprocessing\\image.py:2529, in apply_affine_transform(x, theta, tx, ty, shear, zx, zy, row_axis, col_axis, channel_axis, fill_mode, cval, order)
   2485 @keras_export(\"keras.preprocessing.image.apply_affine_transform\")
   2486 def apply_affine_transform(
   2487     x,
   (...)
   2499     order=1,
   2500 ):
   2501     \"\"\"Applies an affine transformation specified by the parameters given.
   2502 
   2503     Args:
   (...)
   2527         ImportError: if SciPy is not available.
   2528     \"\"\"
-> 2529     if scipy is None:
   2530         raise ImportError(
   2531             \"Image transformations require SciPy. \" \"Install SciPy.\"
   2532         )
   2534     # Input sanity checks:
   2535     # 1. x must 2D image with one or more channels (i.e., a 3D tensor)
   2536     # 2. channels must be either first or last dimension

NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined"
}
```

have double-checked that SciPy is installed within my Conda environment (miniconda3/envs/tf), and the installation was successful. However, the error persists.

Why is this error occurring and how to resolve it?

Comment: What's the _full_ error message (starts with `Traceback`)?

Comment: @ForceBru kindly review my edited section

Comment: This error comes from within keras, not your code. Have you tried restarting the kernel and re-running the notebook?

Comment: @ForceBru yeah I tried but It shows same error.

Comment: What Keras version is this? I can't find this code in the most recent Keras github.

Comment: @NickODell It's 2.10.0